# Storing in the same index using vector of structs

Tags: c++, vector, struct

I'm still fairly rusty at c++ and I'm having trouble understanding my issue. The problem I'm having is that I want to store both the lhs and the rhs into one index until a HASH is read (currently stores lhs into index 0 and rhs into index 1), but I can't seem to find another way to add the rhs into my vector of structs. The code I have:

```
struct Rules
{
string lhs;
vector<string> rhs;
}rule;
```

---

```
vector<Rules> ruleList;
```

---

```
int i = 0;
nextRule:
ttype = getToken();
if(ttype == ID)
{
    ruleList.push_back(rule);
    ruleList[i].lhs = token;
    ttype = getToken();
    if(ttype == ARROW)
    {
        ttype = getToken();
        if(ttype == ID)
        {
            ungetToken();
            while(ttype == ID)
            {
                ttype = getToken();
                if(ttype == HASH)
                {
                    i++;
                    goto nextRule;
                }
                rule.rhs.push_back(token); // PROBLEM IS HERE. Not stored in same index as lhs
            }
            ruleList.push_back(rule); // PROBLEM IS HERE
        }
    }
}
```

Is there an alternative to 'push_back'?

Comment: There are cases when labels and `goto` can be okay to use. Looping is not one of those cases. There are better constructs for looping.

Comment: As for your problem, if you have multiple rules, and multiple entries in each `rule.rhs`, the probability of a "right-hand side" token having the same index as the rule in the global vector will be very low. You might want to rethink your design.